# Custom version of DateFormatter service

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I want to create a slightly different version of the `formatInterval` function. Normally I do this:

```
echo \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval($seconds);
```

I want the final string to say not "1 hour 40 minutes", but "1h 40m" instead, so I was thinking about making a subclass of the core's `DateFormatter` class, and just change the protected `$units` property to define what I want.

How do I do this elegantly in a custom module, "the Drupal way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full story can be found at [Altering existing services, providing dynamic services](https://www.drupal.org/node/2026959), but essentially you need to add a service provider to your module, e.g. (mostly copied from the d.o page above):

```
namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

/**
 * Modifies the date formatter service.
 */
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    // Overrides date.formatter class for custom interval formatting.
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('date.formatter');
    $definition->setClass(DateFormatter::class);
  }
}
```

(assuming your replacement class is `\Drupal\my_module\DateFormatter`)

Comment: Note that this is a good solution if you want *all* intervals to be shown differently. If you just want *some* to be different, then it's better to define it as your own service and only use it where you want to.

Comment: @Berdir I could always do this, but add an optional extra param to `formatInterval()` so that by default it works the same as the original service. (I'm guessing, haven't tried it yet)